# Application Insights didn't log some messages

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

We're using Application Insights to monitor an ASP.NET Core Web API, and I've noticed that we're missing multiple log entries, even though they appear to be logged sequentially in the code.

Here's a snippet of handler class:

```cs
public class EditOrderCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<EditOrderCommand, EditOrderResponseStatus>
{
    readonly ILogger<EditOrderCommandHandler> _logger;
    readonly CqgHostService _cqgHostService;

    public EditOrderCommandHandler(ILogger<EditOrderCommandHandler> logger, CqgHostService cqgHostService)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _cqgHostService = cqgHostService;
    }

    public async Task<EditOrderResponseStatus> Handle(EditOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"edit order: start handling request: {request.SerializeObject()} -- at: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        await _cqgHostService.SendEditOrderAsync(request.AccountId, request.ClOrderId, request.Qty, request.LimitPrice,
            request.StopPrice, request.Duration, request.TenantId, request.OnBehalfOf);

        var editOrderResponseStatus = new EditOrderResponseStatus();
        _logger.LogInformation($"edit order: ending handling request: {request.SerializeObject()} -- at: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        return await Task.FromResult(editOrderResponseStatus);
    }
}
```

When I query Application Insights with:

```
traces
| where timestamp >= datetime('2023-10-12T17:24:00Z') and timestamp <= datetime('2023-10-12T17:26:00Z')
| where message contains "edit order"
| project timestamp, message, customDimensions, operation_Id
| order by timestamp desc
```

I only get:

> 2023-10-12T17:25:50.8118518Z
> edit order: ending handling request: {"ClOrderId":"OHPW-1745-00622_24582026746","Duration":2,"Qty":{"Significand":1,"HasSignificand":true,"Exponent":0,"HasExponent":true},"LimitPrice":5.2350,"StopPrice":0,"CreationDate":"2023-10-12T12:25:50.6475684-05:00","Instrument":"F.US.ZCEZ24","TenantId":"2347ef30-a972-4c99-ac2f-23e4c971adad","AccountId":1769007,"OnBehalfOf":"JBenson2"} -- at: 10/12/2023 5:25:50 PM

The log entry for `edit order: start handling request` is missing, even though both log entries should execute in quick succession.

Any idea why these specific log entries might be missing in Application Insights during this timestamp?

```cs
builder.Logging
    .AddApplicationInsights(builder.Configuration.ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey())
    .AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(typeof(Program).FullName, LogLevel.Trace)
    .AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(typeof(Startup).FullName, LogLevel.Trace)
    .AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Information)
    .AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft", LogLevel.Information)
    .AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Default", LogLevel.Information);
```

### Edit

I found this nice article https://medium.com/@otten.nl/missing-traces-exceptions-in-application-insights-7609111369d

and executed the following query:

```
union requests, dependencies, pageViews, browserTimings, exceptions, traces
| where timestamp >= datetime('2023-10-12T17:24:00Z') and timestamp <= datetime('2023-10-12T17:26:00Z')
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100 / avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType
| order by itemType, timestamp asc
```

This is what it shows:

[image]

Comment: Do you have sampling enabled on your App Insights? Also could you post your appSettings.json snippet related to AppInsights logging settings?

Comment: @toadflakz, I realized `options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;` was missing. That's probably the reason. I'm not sure about _Ingestion Sampling_